# C# Windows application with SQL Server database - dataloss while unexpected power off

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have C# Windows application with a SQL Server 2014 Express database. While running the application, it inserts / updates some records using ADO.Net. When PC gets shutdown unexpectedly due to power failure, then all saved/updated records in database are getting lost.

When we close the application all data are stored properly.

Comment: If your power outage happens while inserting, *before* the transaction can be committed - then it is **expected** behavior that on next startup, the non-committed changes are **rolled back** - and that's a *good thing!* Just re-try these inserts again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply James,
existing applicaion I am not using transaction for committing database records,
if I close the application normally after insert or updation of some records then it save correctly. but why records are lost while application ends with power off case.
I also add transaction for committing each record but in power off case transactions are not worked.

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET transactions is the answer. You can read more [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971557.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Farukh
I have already checked with sql transactions but is was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;

var connection = new SqlConnection("Your connection");
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    SqlTransaction transaction = null;
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        command.Transaction = transaction;
        command.CommandText = "Your query";
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (transaction != null) transaction.Rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
       connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider some `using`statements here ;-)

Comment: Thanks Leena for reply...
I have already write same code,
plz understand my scenario detail
I am continuously insert and update records in table in 1 minute I insert 30 rows update 20 rows,
during this execution if i direct power off my PC then all 30 inserted record and 20 updated records were lost,
I am using above code.